# PDO error when wrong host name

Tags: php

I'm trying to catch the error on the database connection but I get the an error when I enter a wrong host name only, here's my code :

```
try
{
    $mysqlconnection = new PDO('mysql:host=localshost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{

die('Erreur : ' . $ex->getMessage());

}
```

And here's the error I get :

[image]

Why do I get this error ONLY if I set a wrong hostname ?

Comment: Turn the warnings on (on your PDO connection - `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` and `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`) and use `PDOException` instead of `Exception` in your catch argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to turn the exceptions on and use `PDOException` for the caught exception.

```
try {
    $mysqlconnection = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localshost;dbname=test',
        'root', 'yourPasswordHere'
    );
    $mysqlconnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die('Erreur : ' . $ex->getMessage());
    // or 
    // die('Erreur:' . PHP_EOL . $ex->getTraceAsString());
}
```

For me it outputs

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known