# PDO silently testing connectivity

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way I can either validate the connection parameters before making a connection using them, or alternatively turn off the warnings, so I can handle the errors myself? (by the way, ERRMODE_SILENT did not work)

I want my application to handle the errors, instead of displaying them in the output. This is a part of the constructor:

```
 try {
    $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;port=$db_port;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);

 } catch (PDOException $e){
    $this->connEstablished = false;
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: It throws an exception... catch it. What is the problem with your solution?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, which I am not sure I completely do, you are displaying $this->error in your view which is showing the exception message, when you catch the exception, just set $this->error to the message you want to display eg $this->error = 'invalid DB params';. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Guys, catching the error is no problem. The problem is the warning which is shown in the browser, if the data is wrong. (The data is entered by the user.) It is an Ajax application and I cannot afford to output anything (warnings / errors) before my JSON output.

Comment: What warnings / errors? The PDO constructor doesn't do that. It just throws an exception.

Comment: This is the warning which I get:
<b>Warning</b>:  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in (...)

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/14421602/508666?

Comment: He wanted to know why connection failed, but I just want to make it silent. There was no solution for me in the other post.

Comment: I found a workaround myself. I buffer the output by ob_start(); beginning with the connection attempt and set it back by ob_end_clean(); afterwards. This way the warning (which is generated only if the hostname is invalid!) does not show up in the php output, which needs to remain clean for Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your 'display_errors' setting in php.ini. See the [PHP configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) documentation.

if 'display_errors' is 'On' then it will output any errors or warnings to the browser. Setting it to 'Off' will prevent this, and is almost always a good idea.

This is controlled via php.ini, but can also be changed at runtime using the built-in function `ini_set`, which is useful if you do not have control over your environment (using a hosted server, etc.)

You can check the current value with `ini_get('display_errors')` and turn it off with `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off')`.